# Adding click functions to DOM elements dynamically

Tags: jquery

In my test code, I have a simple div that I'm using as a container for 5 loop created div elements. I try adding a click function to all 5 div elements, but only the last one is given a click function.

```
<div id="testbed"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        $("#testbed").html($("#testbed").html() + "<div id='" + i + "'>Hello!</div>");
        $("#" + i).click(function () {
            alert(i);
        });
    }
});
</script>
```

Interestingly enough, instead of alerting 4, it alerts 5. I don't know why it's only applying the click function to the last div element and not the first 4.

Comment: Hey, I appreciate the time that you guys put into this. A few of you have already posted working examples, and I'll be going through each response carefully, since you all used different examples. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also do something to this effect:

```
$.each([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], function(index, value) { 
     $("#testbed").append("<div id='" + index + "'>Hello!</div>");
     $("#" + index).click(function () {
         alert(index);
     });
 });
```

Comment: This was the first working example that I came across. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

All of your `click` handlers are sharing the same `i` variable.
Since, after the loop, `i` is `5`, they all say `5`.

You need to create each handler in a separate function that takes `i` as a parameter, so that each handler will get its own `i`.

For example:

```
function buildElement(i) {
    $("#testbed").html($("#testbed").html() + "<div id='" + i + "'>Hello!</div>");
    $("#" + i).click(function () {
        alert(i);
    });
}


for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    buildElement(i);
}
```

Comment: How would that look like? Do I literally just create a new function outside of that loop, and loop through those div elements adding click functions?

Comment: With that example, it still doesn't add the click function to the other divs.

Comment: By re-setting the HTML, you're clearing any state in the DOM elements, including event handlers.  You should call `append()` instead.

Comment: Also, you should build the DOM element with jQuery and add the handler to it before appending, and not use an ID.  (IDs, by the way, cannot start with a number)

Answer (score 0):

The following is called a javascript closure. At the moment of binding, you run the anonymous function that returns another function that does `alert(i)` when the event is fired. The first anonymous function "wraps" creates another level of variable scope for the i, so when the original i is incremented later on, the i inside the anonymous function remains untouched. Nifty little trick.

```
<div id="testbed"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        $("#testbed").html($("#testbed").html() + "<div id='" + i + "'>Hello!</div>");
        $("#" + i).click(function (i) {
            return function(evt) {
                // inside here, you have access to the event object too
                alert(i);
            };
        }(i));
    }
});
</script>
```

More information at [javascript closures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

Btw if you wish to add click events to all divs, you can't replace them with `.html()`
 in every loop, use `.append()` instead, like so:

```
<div id="testbed"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        $("#testbed").append("<div id='" + i + "'>Hello!</div>");
        $("#" + i).click(function (i) {
            return function(evt) {
                // inside here, you have access to the event object too
                alert(i);
            };
        }(i));
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: This example didn't work. It only added a click function to the last div item.

Comment: I mean, I'm the only responder who gave you the correct solution, not a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the click event to the object.

```
    $(function(){

      $('#testbed').empty();       

     for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
          $('<div />').text('Hello').attr('id', i).click(function(){
              alert($(this).attr('id'));
          }).appendTo('#testbed');
       }

    });
```